# Settings for search in JabRef

Tags: windows, jabref

Recently, my installation of JabRef (in Windows 7) started working differently in two ways:

1. If I use the shortcut for search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), it starts out by doing an Incremental search. If I want to do a Global Search, I either have to move the mouse to that bullet or keep taping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> until it gets to the correct bullet. Is there a way to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> start at Global Search right away?
2. When I do a Global Search, the results now open in a new window. It used to simply sort the search results in the present window, removing those entries that don't match the search criterion. Can I get back to the old behavior?

Comment: (An old question I know.)  Have you tried reinstalling, or installing a [newer (or older) version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jabref/files/jabref/)?

Answer (score 3):

JabRef should remember the search method between uses: unless there is an issue with your installation, setting 'global search' on one use should result in this being the search method the next time you start JabRef.

The 'Global search' option deliberately opens a second window with the results. It sounds like you are looking for a 'Filter' search, which shows only matching entries in the main window.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience, so I finally figured out that the "problem" is due to an entirely different cause, so I decided to paste it here that someone else might get helped.

I was using the second monitor so that the resolution was completely different on my two monitors. As a result, the jabref was not displaying properly the windows. In fact, one part of the window for the article details overwhelmed the rest, and the resulting list was squeezed into a thin line and gave the impression that it is not shown at all.

Also, from the "view" menu, one can also switch on and off a few options, so that the desired content may be shown properly.